# @EJB - Inject into Servlet requires type Interface, not Class (bean)

Tags: java, servlets, dependency-injection, annotations, ejb

I encountered this strange issue and hope someone can clarify.

1) I have a simple EJB, which consist of an interface `DemoSessionInterface`, and an implementing class `DemoSesssionBean` (code provided below).

2) A simple servlet where I inject an instance of the above-mentioned EJB

```
@EJB
DemoSessionInterface bean;
```

As you see, if I declare variable `bean` as of type Interface (DemoSessionInterface), then it works fine. However, if I change the type of bean to the class (the bean itself), like this:

```
@EJB
DemoSesssionBean bean;
```

then weblogic throws me an error when I am deploying the app:

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: weblogic.application.naming.ReferenceResolutionException:
 [J2EE:160200]Error 
resolving ejb-ref "test.MyServlet/bean" from module "web" of application "web".
 The ejb-ref does not have an ejb-link and the JNDI name of the target bean has
 not been specified. Attempts to automatically link the ejb-ref to its target 
bean failed because no EJBs in the application were found to implement the 
"ejb.DemoSessionBean" interface. Link or map this ejb-ref to its target EJB and 
ensure the interfaces declared in the ejb-ref are correct.
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ReferenceResolutionFlow.resolveReferences
(ReferenceResolutionFlow.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ReferenceResolutionFlow.prepare
(ReferenceResolutionFlow.java:31)
```

So is it true that I am required to declare `bean` always as Interface, not the Bean itself? What if I have multiple classes that implement `DemoSessionInterface`? Would that cause conflicts?

=======
Code:

```
@Local
public interface DemoSessionInterface {
    public String getHelloString();
}


@Stateless//(mappedName = "MrBean")
public class DemoSessionBean implements DemoSessionInterface {
    public DemoSessionBean() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getHelloString(){
        return "Hello there; How are you????";
    }
}

@javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns={"/hi"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    DemoSessionInterface bean; 

    protected void doGet(...)
```

Comment: Which version of Weblogic is this?

Comment: It's wls1213 (version 12)

Comment: If you have multiple implementations then you specify what implementation to inject by [`@EJB(beanName="ImplementationClass")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html#beanName%28%29)

Comment: This indeed disambiguates beans that implement the same interface. So the remaining question is only why I have to declare bean as of Interface type, but not Class? I saw some code from a  big project where people declared it as Class, but not sure why it doesn't work in my simple example.